# PDO update doesn't work, no errors

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I'm staring myself blind on the fact why I can't execute this update statement.

```
$prepare = 'UPDATE plugins SET status=? WHERE name=?';
$execute = array("0", "testplugin");

$statement = $this->_dbConnectionInstance->prepare($prepare);
$statement->execute($execute);
```

I set error reporting to `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` and it produces no errors. However, the row in the database is not changed after execution. Executing the query directly on the database (PHPMyAdmin, replacing the question marks with the values) does work, strangely enough.
Also, the database connection is okay (a simple query `'SELECT * FROM plugins'` does work).

[image: The database structure]

Comment: Maybe there is no plugins row with name == testplugin?

Comment: There is one, I double checked it ;)

Comment: Ok. Just for checking, but the first line does not end in `;`.

Comment: Should be there, this piece code is a shortened version, but perfectly representative for the full piece.

Comment: What do you get as a value of `$statement->rowCount()` immediately after `$statement->execute($execute)`? It should be `1`, the number of rows affected.  If it's `0`, that's a sign that your `WHERE` statement isn't finding any rows.

Comment: It says 1 row is affected...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used an online available database class ([PDO-Quick](https://github.com/techjacker/PDO-Quick)), which has an architectural error in it. When instantiating the database class, a transaction is started (1). But, nowhere in the class is committed and the transaction stays always 'open'. I now begin a transaction before every query, commit it after execution and rollback when any error occurs (2).

**(1)**

```
$this->_dbConnectionInstance->beginTransaction();
```

**(2)**

```
try {
    $this->_dbConnectionInstance->beginTransaction();
    $stmt = $this->_dbConnectionInstance->prepare($prepare);

    $stmt->execute($execute);
    $this->_dbConnectionInstance->commit();
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    $this->_dbConnectionInstance->rollBack();
    exit();
}
```